# ¿Como puedo detectar si están usando una versión modificada de mi app android?

Tags: java, android

He desarrollado una app para android en la cuál mis ganancias son por medio de ads y me he encontrado en algunos foros versiones modificadas que bloquean toda la publicidad, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de detectar estas modificaciones y de algún modo restringir el servicio a estos usuarios.

Cabe resaltar que la aplicación consiste en un servicio de video por streaming por lo que es necesario estar conectado a internet para usarse.

Comment: Si como dices son versiones modificadas, significa que alguien ha tomado tu app, la ha revertido y a partir del código ha creado una nueva app, subiendo el `.apk` a esos foros o páginas que mencionas. Ante eso, lo único que puedes hacer es tratar de proteger el código de tu app de alguna manera, de forma que no puedan hacer ingeniería inversa del mismo para plagiarlo. Otra cosa que puedes hacer es quejarte ante los responsables den los foros que la publican.

Answer (score 1):

es correcto el comentario de arriba, lo correcto seria que ofusques tu código así evitaras que modifiquen tu app.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290023/obfuscation-in-android-studio

saludos, el link que te anexo explican como hacerlo suerte